# Hard coding @PathVariable in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, path-variables

I am new to java and am still trying to wrap around my mind around many of its concepts.

Right now in my application that pulls in data from an external api. I am trying to hardcode a path, for now, to make sure that I am getting the response I am expecting (this is a temporary interaction as eventually, I want the app to be stateless. If I pass a hardcoded value for @PathVariable in my controller with the variable defined above the code doesn't read the value.

Where should I be placing the hard-coded value and am I defining it the correct way?

Code:

```
String identificationCode ="abcd";
@RequestMapping(value ="/download/{identificationCode}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
String downloadDocument(@PathVariable(value="identificationCode") String identificationCode) {
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Comment: Dont you mix up server and client here?

Answer (score 0):

`value` is a alias for name. That means that `@PathVariable(value="identificationCode")` specifies name of variable for this parameter, but not value. [See](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here `"/download/{identificationCode}"`

`identificationCode` is not interpolated by the value of the String declared there :

```
String identificationCode ="abcd";
```

It will just produce the String : `"/download/{identificationCode}"`.

You could write it :

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/download/"+identificationCode, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

but it will not work either as `identificationCode` is not a constant expression.

So what you want is just :

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/download/abc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Use this way if you don't need to reference the String somewhere else.

Otherwise as alternative declare `identificationCode` as a constant expression (and you can also do this `static` by the way) :

```
final static String identificationCode ="abcd";
```

And you could so use it :

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/download/"+identificationCode, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace {identificationCode} with your hard code value in @RequestMapping(value ="/download/{identificationCode}". Later, when you want the dynamic nature of path, you can go as you have currently coded.